# Adding a slider to ILNumerics Plot

Tags: ilnumerics

I'd like to make use of an ILNumerics 3D plot but I would like to add a slider control.  The slider would be responsible for filtering values on the backing data set so I can visualize my data under certain conditions.  Basically, user moves slider and plot automatically updates based on criteria set by slider.

The functionality that I am looking for is very similar to Mathematica's manipulate feature.  Is this type of functionality possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Interactivity is one specialty of ILNumerics. All objects can be modified dynamically. Simply place your code into the event handler of the slider and change everyting you need there.

Afterwards, call Configure() on the affected part of the scene in order to lock your changes in. ILPanel.Refresh() causes an immediate refresh of the display.

Comment: Any examples of doing this?  Did not see this in documentation.

Comment: Cannot find a reference right now. Why don't you start and try yourself - it is really straightforward! If you encounter any problems, let us know.